# Unable to get data for id

Tags: mysql, rest, api, metamug

I'm using metamug to build my REST API. I wrote a query to fetch name of student, provided the id. But doesn't work. Gives 204 status code in response.

```
<Request method="GET">
    <Desc> Get All Attendance </Desc>
    <Query>
        SELECT name from attendance 
        where id= $id 
    </Query>
</Request>
```

https://api.metamug.com/classroom/v1.0/attd?id=2

My Table query is as follows

```
create table attendance (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(200))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there `$id` is a **special variable** which is used as **Resource Identifier** in an `Item` type of request in `Metamug` (for more info on `Collection`/`Item` request see [Collection and Item Request](https://metamug.com/docs/resource-file.php#collection-&-item-request) and on `Resource Identifier` see [The Resource Identifier](https://metamug.com/blog/why-rest-api-backend.php#the-resource-identifier)), here you're making a `Collection` request while using a `resource identifier`. You'll have to slightly modify your resource file to

Add the following attribute in your Request tag.

```
item="true"
```

#### Item Request

```
<Request method="GET" item="true">
    <Desc> Get All Attendance </Desc>
    <Query>
        SELECT name from attendance 
        where id= $id 
    </Query>
</Request>
```

Now to pass a value for your `$id` variable you'll have to use it as path parameter and not like query string viz.

`https://api.metamug.com/classroom/v1.0/attd/{value that you've to pass}`

That value will be held by `$id` variable so in your case, it'll be

https://api.metamug.com/classroom/v1.0/attd/2

Comment: you mean `https://api.metamug.com/classroom/v1.0/attd/{id}` Now it works.

Comment: @Sorter Yes, that's the way.